# Extending lists directly from returned lists of functions

Tags: python, list

I want the output of returned values from a function to be extended to a set of lists.

```
def func():
    return [-1,2],[4,1]
f=[1,2]
g=[3,4]
f,g=func() #How make it append
print f,g

#Expected Output:
[1,2,-1,2] [3,4,4,1]
```

For one list, I can do `f.extend(func())` but what about multiple lists.
Creating temporary variables is not preferred.

Comment: "Creating temporary variables is not preffered." - any particular reason why not? Do you need to scale this in some dimension, perhaps extending some number N lists at a time instead of two? Pretty much any solution is going to require temporary variables, but we can still try to make it as clean as possible.

Comment: create temporary variables

Comment: In python you can simply extend lists by using the '+' operator. That should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 4):

Why not pass the function two parameters

```
def func(l1 ,l2):
    return l1+[-1,2],l2+[4,1]

f = [1,2]
g = [3,4]
f,g = func(f,g)
print f,g
```

produces

```
[1, 2, -1, 2] [3, 4, 4, 1]
```

However, it may be easier to let the function extend the lists and avoid the return value altogether

```
def func(l1 ,l2):
    l1.extend([-1,2])
    l2.extend([4,1])

f = [1,2]
g = [3,4]
func(f,g)
print f,g
```

Comment: This feels wrong, the function doesn't really care about the inputs, it just appends...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I see your point, but the OP is assigning/wants to use the return value, so I've suggested something that works under that model

Comment: People want to do all kind of weird stuff, helping to do that isn't necessarily a good idea.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I ignore the context the code is in, so I followed the OP's approach. Please see my edit, I've added another option

Answer (score 3):

If this question is more general, and you cannot modify your function, use `zip`:

```
>>> f,g = (x+y for x,y in zip((f,g), func()))
>>> f
[1, 2, -1, 2]
>>> g
[3, 4, 4, 1]
```